# Elasticsearch: how to group by the result before echo result?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version is 5.0.
I setup more fields in aggs below:

[image]

the result is below:

[image]

there have some methods to get the min and max values in one field, and divide them to five or four and then count how many docs in each stage?
same as this:

[image]

Comment: You can try the [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html)

Comment: @Val yes. but the range should be defined manually at first. i want the  range is dynamical to created by ES according the results. If the filter term is changed, the range will be created again according the new results.

Comment: There's no such thing I'm afraid.

Comment: @Val i search it on google and no method to do it. somebody suggest use two query to implement it. i will try it. thanks for your help.